# How to deploy a Spring-Boot-Webflux application to Tomcat standalone server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

A normal spring-web application can be deployed to `tomcat` standalone as `war` file as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Question: how can I deploy such an application after migrating to `spring-webflux` to tomcat?

Docs say:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler

> To deploy as a WAR to any Servlet 3.1+ container, you can extend and
> include AbstractReactiveWebInitializer in the WAR. That class wraps an
> HttpHandler with ServletHttpHandlerAdapter and registers that as a
> Servlet.

So but there is no example how to.

I tried as follows, which gives an exception:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends AbstractReactiveWebInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {MyApplication.class};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
MyApplication.java:13:8
java: cannot access javax.servlet.ServletException
  class file for javax.servlet.ServletException not found
```

Comment: You have `@SpringBootApplication` you don't need it. Just extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Be aware that using Reactive in Tomcat isn't fully reactive! you only get the async capabilities of the Servlet API no backpressure etc. Basically you already had it as needed and you don't need to change anything.

Comment: If I simply extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`, I get the same exception! That's why I'm looking for a workaround at all. Because `SpringBootServletInitializer` also requires `javax.servlet.ServletException` , which does not exist using `spring-boot-starter-webflux`only.

Comment: Are you deploying to tomcat 10 as that isn't supported yet. You shouldn't need a workaround in the first place.

Comment: Maybe the following is the problem: I'm first trying to start the application as `jar` locally for dev. Only for production will package as a `war` and deploy to `tomcat9`.

Comment: You don't need the `jar` you can just run the `war` as a `jar`. So basically your build is complicated. You can just use packaging `war` in maven, make `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` scoped as provided, and when running as a `war` (or just the application) you can do `java -jar your.war` and it will start. All in all you shouldn't need a workaround, the fact that you get a `ClassNotFoundException` makes me think you are either deploying to Tomcat10 (instead of 9) or your Tomcat installation is crippled.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did not have the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency included yet. That works! Would you mind adding this as a real answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use case is not supported by the Spring Boot team, [as explained in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment.war). Even if some features might work, you'll find many limitations and bugs to this approach - and it seems [you've started to experience just this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30212).